# Detect the last element of a null terminated vector

Tags: c, vector, null-pointer

In the documentation for using sockets there is a description of the `hostent` structure: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Host-Names.html#Host-Names

For the `h_addr_list` field it says that it is a vector terminated with a null pointer.
So, what I try to do is:

```c
struct in_addr *addr = (struct in_addr *)hostent->h_addr_list[0];
while (addr != NULL) {
  // ...
  addr++;
}
```

I expected that `addr` variable is NULL when it reaches the last element in the vector, because that element should be a NULL pointer.
But on practice that does not happen. `addr` never becomes `NULL`.

```c
// hostent->h_addr_list contains 4 meaningful elements
struct in_addr *addr = (struct in_addr *)hostent->h_addr_list[0];
addr++;
addr++;
addr++;
addr == (struct in_addr *)hostent->h_addr_list[3]; // true
addr++;
// here I expected addr to be NULL to terminate the vector, but...
NULL == addr; // false!!!
addr == (struct in_addr *)hostent->h_addr_list[4]; // false

// just to check that it actually NULL terminated
NULL == hostent->h_addr_list[4]; // true
addr = (struct in_addr *)hostent->h_addr_list[4];
NULL == addr; // true
```

So, why is it like this?
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: You cannot cause a pointer to become NULL by incrementing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the documentation:

> char **h_addr_list
>
> This is the vector of addresses for the host. (Recall that the host might be connected to multiple networks and have different addresses on each one.) The vector is terminated by a null pointer.

`h_addr_list` is a pointer to a pointer to a char, so the last *pointer* will be NULL, not the pointer to the pointer itself. Otherwise it would have to be located at very specific memory for it to be zero after a certain number of increments! Just do:

```
char **addr_list = hostent->h_addr_list;
while (*addr_list != NULL) {
    // Now *addr points to a valid address
    struct in_addr *addr = (struct in_addr *)*addr_list;

    addr_list++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a vector of pointers. It's the last element in the vector (a pointer) that is NULL, not the address to that element. So try `while (*addr != NULL)`.

Also, that you needed the cast `(struct in_addr *)` for the starting value of the pointer (to silence a warning?) is a strong indication that that part of your code is wrong.